# File output node and output panel both exporting during animation

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, image

I have an animation ready to render but there is a small annoying issue. I currently have a basic file output node to export the raw render and a mist pass and they are both set to export to the correct folder and that is all working fine. The issue is the file output panel is still exporting images. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: It is. The only 2 nodes in the compositor is a render layer and a file output

Comment: This is a great question that deserves to get answered! This feature is really annoying.